VBA Code to loop through range of cells and color the font of those which have red down arrow from Conditional formatting
I have the following data in the range A1:B5.



A
B




↓5
↑21


↑35
↓3



The rules are as follows -
Conditional formatting rules
So 3 Icon Set, green up arrow when value is >=20, yellow arrow when <20 and >=15, and red down arrow when <15.
What I want to achieve is check if there's a red down arrow in the cell and if so, color the text in red (255,0,0).
I asked ChatGPT for help and it spit out this code:
Sub ColorRedArrows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Define the worksheet and range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your actual sheet name
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:B20")

    ' Loop through each cell in the range
    For Each cell In rng
        ' Check if cell has conditional formatting with an icon set and a red down arrow
        On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors if DisplayFormat is not applicable
        If Not cell.DisplayFormat Is Nothing Then
            ' Check if the cell's displayed icon is a red down arrow
            If cell.DisplayFormat.IconIndex = 1 Then
                ' Change the font color to red
                cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 ' Resume normal error handling
    Next cell
End Sub

The code colors all the cells with the data and not just the ones with red down arrow.
I turned to Claude and it demonstrated different approach. Here's the code:
Sub ColorRedArrows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cf As IconSetCondition
    
    ' Define the worksheet and range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your actual sheet name
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:B20")
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the range
    For Each cell In rng
        ' Check if cell has conditional formatting
        If cell.FormatConditions.Count > 0 Then
            ' Check if the conditional formatting is an icon set
            If cell.FormatConditions(1).Type = xlIconSet Then
                Set cf = cell.FormatConditions(1).IconSet
                ' Check if the icon set has at least 3 icons (to ensure it has a red down arrow)
                If cf.IconSet.ID = xlIconSet3Arrows Then
                    ' Check if the cell's value triggers the red down arrow (lowest threshold)
                    If cell.Value <= cf.IconCriteria(1).Value Then
                        ' Change the font color to red
                        cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

However, the code doesn't run and I keep getting "Compile error: Type mismatch" error. None of the LLMs I tried managed to fix this error and I can't seem to find a solution myself as well, so any help would be appreciated.
EDIT: Thank you, ouroboros1, for the provided solution. I realized I hadn't explained what I was trying to achieve well enough.
That's how my tables look.

I have several sheets in my workbook, and each of those contains a table that looks more or less like the one in the screenshot. These were exported from an online platform and the conditional formatting rules weren't set up in Excel. I'm saying that just to clarify why the very same figure could have an Up triangle in one cell and Down triangle in another.
So instead of the Up and Down arrows (xlIconGreenUpArrow - 1 and xlIconRedDownArrow - 3) in the worksheet we have xl3Triangles (xlIconGreenUpTriangle - 45 and xlIconRedDownTriangle - 47).
What I'd like to achieve is to color the font of the cells that contain xlIconGreenUpTriangle in RGB(0, 176, 80) and the cells that contain xlIconRedDownTriangle in RGB(255, 0, 0). See screenshot below for reference.

I found a rather lame way to achieve this and here's my code so far:
Sub ColorCFCells()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim col As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastColumn = ws.Cells(11, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For col = 3 To lastColumn ' Loop through columns C to the last used column
        ' Clear any existing AutoFilter before applying a new one
        If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        
        ' Apply filter for red down triangle (Item 1) in the current column
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(11, col), ws.Cells(lastRow, col)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Triangles).Item(1), Operator:=xlFilterIcon
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Loop through the visible cells and apply red font color
        For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(11, col), ws.Cells(lastRow, col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
        Next cell
        On Error GoTo 0
        ws.ShowAllData
        
        ' Apply filter for green up triangle (Item 3) in the current column
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(11, col), ws.Cells(lastRow, col)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Triangles).Item(3), Operator:=xlFilterIcon
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Loop through the visible cells and apply green font color
        For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(11, col), ws.Cells(lastRow, col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) ' Green color
        Next cell
        On Error GoTo 0
        ws.ShowAllData
    Next col
    
    ' Set the font color of row 11 (across the columns from C to the last column) to black
    ws.Range("C11:" & ws.Cells(11, lastColumn).Address).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    
    ' Clear any filter at the end
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub

Currently, for each column, I look for a Down triangle, filter the cells, color the visible cells red, remove the filter and repeat for the Up triangle and the rest of the columns.
I realize it's not a very smart approach, as, for example, sometimes in the tables, there are merged cells and then this code doesn't work; sometimes the data starts from column B rather than column C, etc.
That's why I'm trying to find a better solution that would loop through the used ranges in each worksheet and achieve the desired result, and I'm hoping someone could help me with that.

This seems to be an error in the Microsoft documentation. xlIconSet is actually a class; the enum value is xlIconSets. So add an extra s after If cell.FormatConditions(1).Type = xlIconSet

Building upon the above comment - if you ever wonder whether enum value is real (e.g. Excel enum in Access), write ?xlIconSets in the immediate window. In the case of ?xlIconSets it return 6 and in  the case of xlIconSet it returns an error message box.

@paul: nice catch! Here in the docs indeed. That won’t make the AI-generated code work as desired though. It is otherwise “guessing” what to do.

To achieve the desired result manually, is quite easy. The condition:
=(VALUE-MIN(RNG))/(MAX(RNG)-MIN(RNG))<PERCENTAGE

So, you could just add a formatting rule with a formula:
=(A1-MIN($A$1:$B$5))/(MAX($A$1:$B$5)-MIN($A$1:$B$5))<0.15


To do that programmatically, via vba, is (potentially) tricky, because:

The application of a formatting rule cannot be retrieved from a Range object itself (e.g., it doesn't exist as a property of Range.DisplayFormat, as ChatGPT seems to guess), and
xlIconRedDownArrow is not necessarily linked to the minimum threshold of any xlIconSet. E.g., you could do something as bizarre as this:



The code below assumes:

use of xl3Arrows.
default use of xlIconRedDownArrow for the first IconCriterion.Index: minimum threshold.
default use of .Type: "Percent" (= 3).

Sub ColorRedArrows()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iconSetCond As IconSetCondition, iconCrit As IconCriterion
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    Dim nextOperator As Long, invOperator As String
    Dim nextValue As Double
    
    Dim firstAddress As String, rngAddress As String
    Dim myFormula As String

    'Define range
    Set rng = Range("A1:B5")

    With rng
        'Loop through conditional formats
        For i = 1 To .FormatConditions.Count
            '.Type = 6 (= "xlIconSets", see comment @Paul)
            If rng.FormatConditions(i).Type = 6 Then
                Set iconSetCond = rng.FormatConditions(i)
                'Loop through icon criteria
                For j = 1 To iconSetCond.IconCriteria.Count
                    Set iconCrit = iconSetCond.IconCriteria(j)
                    'Find Red Down Arrow (3 = "xlIconRedDownArrow")
                    If iconCrit.Icon = 3 Then
                        'Check if it is first criterion (default)
                        If iconCrit.Index = 1 Then
                            'Get operator *next* index
                            nextOperator = iconSetCond.IconCriteria(j + 1) _
                            .Operator
                            '7 = ">=", 5 = ">" (only options): invert
                            invOperator = IIf(nextOperator = 7, "<", "<=")
                            'Get value *next* index
                            nextValue = iconSetCond.IconCriteria(j + 1) _
                            .Value * 0.01
                        End If
                        'Exit loop
                        j = iconSetCond.IconCriteria.Count
                    End If
                Next j
                'Exit main loop
                i = .FormatConditions.Count
            End If
        Next i

        'Get address first cell in range (relative row & col)
        firstAddress = rng.Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False)
        'Get address range (absolute row & col)
        rngAddress = rng.Address(True, True)
        
        'Build formula
        myFormula = "=(" & firstAddress & "-MIN(" & rngAddress & "))/(MAX(" _
        & rngAddress & ")-MIN(" & rngAddress & "))" & invOperator & nextValue

        'Add new rule
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=myFormula
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With

End Sub

Result at MAX=100 and MAX=60:



If you want to fix the font color rather than create a new conditional formatting rule, change the last part. Something like:
Sub ColorRedArrows()
    'Dims, set rng ...
    With rng
        For i = 1 To .FormatConditions.Count
            '... Above logic to get "invOperator", "nextValue"
        Next i

        Dim minValue As Long, maxValue As Long
        Dim Cell As Range
        Dim percValue As Double, bool As Boolean
        
        minValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
        maxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
        
        'Loop through cells, check rule
        For Each Cell In .Cells
            percValue = (Cell.Value - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue)
            If invOperator = "<" Then
                bool = percValue < nextValue
            Else
                bool = percValue <= nextValue
            End If
            
            If bool Then
                Cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                'Reset all other fonts to black
                Cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next Cell
    End With

End Sub

Of course, whenever data in rng changes, you need to rerun this to avoid mismatches between fixed fonts and recalculated icons. You could use a WorksheetChange event to automate that:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:B5")) Is Nothing Then
        Call ColorRedArrows
    End If

End Sub

In action:

